# Widget logic not working

Tags: widgets

I am using the [Widget Logic](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/) plugin to display a widget only on certain pages.

I use the condition

```
is_page(10,16,19)
```

to specify the pages I want the widget to display on.

However, the widget does not display on these pages.

I have double checked the page ID is correct, and I have cleared my browser cache, yet the widget isn't being displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the [`is_page()` Codex entry](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page). You need to pass multiple Page IDs as an *array*:

```
is_page( array( 10,16,19 ) )
```